# Multiple Moveable Resizable Windows with HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, resize, draggable

I am attempt to make multiple moveable resizable windows using only HTML / CSS.

Based on [this post from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/draggable-elements/) I have made two windows and they can both be moved.

However, the second window interferes with the first window if it is placed down to the right of the 1st.

The `.move_wrapper` of the second group is overlaying the "resize" region of the 1st `.mover` and blocking events.

Tried combinations of pointer-events, display, z-index, and currently nothing tried seems to fix the issue.

Anybody know if there's a way to have the two windows like below, while having them both be moveable no matter where they are?  And preferentially, something that could scale up to N windows with no issues.

```js
function main(){
    // Empty function, not what was necessary for snippets
}
```

```css
  
    
:root {
    /* variables for use in var() functions ex: 'display: var(--menuDisplay);'
    --menuDisplay: "none";
    */
    
    --resizer-size: 18px;
}
            
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.move_wrapper {
    width: min-content;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -2;
}

.mover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 64px;
    min-height: 64px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mover:hover {
}

.mover_grab {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: var(--resizer-size);
    height: var(--resizer-size);
}

.mover_grab:hover ~ .move_wrapper {
    background: #196EAC;
    z-index: 1;
}
    

.mover_icon {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: var(--resizer-size);
    height: var(--resizer-size);
    z-index: -1;
    
    background: black;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="white" \
      d="M13,11H18L16.5,9.5L17.92,8.08L21.84,12L17.92,15.92L16.5,14.5L18,13H13V18L14.5,16.5L15.92,17.92L12,21.84L8.08,17.92L9.5,16.5\
      L11,18V13H6L7.5,14.5L6.08,15.92L2.16,12L6.08,8.08L7.5,9.5L6,11H11V6L9.5,7.5L8.08,6.08L12,2.16L15.92,6.08L14.5,7.5L13,6V11Z" /></svg>')
}

.base_node_frame {
    pointer-events: auto;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 11px;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    
    box-shadow:
        inset #009688 0 0 0 5px, 
        inset #059c8e 0 0 0 6px, 
        inset #8ce9ff 0 0 0 10px, 
        inset #48e4d6 0 0 0 11px;
}

.base_node_header {
    background: #196EAC;
    
    width: calc( 100% - 10px );
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.base_node {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    z-index: -1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.base_node_footer {
    background: #196EAC;
    
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    z-index: -1;
    
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="move_wrapper">
    <div class="mover_grab">
        <div class="base_node_frame">
            <div class="base_node_header"><div class="mover_icon"></div><span>Header Region</span></div>
            <div class="base_node">Let the user resize both the height and the width of this div element.</div>
            <div class="base_node_footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mover"></div>
</div>
<div class="move_wrapper">
    <div class="mover_grab">
        <div class="base_node_frame">
            <div class="base_node_header"><div class="mover_icon"></div><span>To Do List</span></div>
            <div class="base_node">Second div I would also like to be able to move around independently like in Windows</div>
            <div class="base_node_footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mover" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"></div>
</div>
```

***EDIT 12/12/2023***

Slight improvement using a `:hover` effect on the `.mover_wrapper`.  Problem is that it generates a lot of Z-depth fighting, so its not really a solution.  It allows the windows to be moved, yet still is finicky about whether it will grab them reliably.

```js
function main(){
    // Empty function, not what was necessary for snippets
}
```

```css
  
    
:root {
    /* variables for use in var() functions ex: 'display: var(--menuDisplay);'
    --menuDisplay: "none";
    */
    
    --resizer-size: 18px;
}
            
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.move_wrapper {
    width: min-content;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -2;
}

.move_wrapper:hover {
    z-index: -3;
}

.mover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 64px;
    min-height: 64px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0;
}

.mover_grab {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
    width: var(--resizer-size);
    height: var(--resizer-size);
}
    
.mover_icon {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: var(--resizer-size);
    height: var(--resizer-size);
    z-index: -1;
    
    background: black;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="white" \
      d="M13,11H18L16.5,9.5L17.92,8.08L21.84,12L17.92,15.92L16.5,14.5L18,13H13V18L14.5,16.5L15.92,17.92L12,21.84L8.08,17.92L9.5,16.5\
      L11,18V13H6L7.5,14.5L6.08,15.92L2.16,12L6.08,8.08L7.5,9.5L6,11H11V6L9.5,7.5L8.08,6.08L12,2.16L15.92,6.08L14.5,7.5L13,6V11Z" /></svg>')
}

.base_node_frame {
    pointer-events: auto;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 11px;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    
    box-shadow:
        inset #009688 0 0 0 5px, 
        inset #059c8e 0 0 0 6px, 
        inset #8ce9ff 0 0 0 10px, 
        inset #48e4d6 0 0 0 11px;
}

.base_node_header {
    background: #196EAC;
    
    width: calc( 100% - 10px );
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.base_node {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    z-index: -1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.base_node_footer {
    background: #196EAC;
    
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    z-index: -1;
    
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="move_wrapper">
    <div class="mover_grab">
        <div class="base_node_frame">
            <div class="base_node_header"><div class="mover_icon"></div><span>Header Region</span></div>
            <div class="base_node">Let the user resize both the height and the width of this div element.</div>
            <div class="base_node_footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mover"></div>
</div>
<div class="move_wrapper">
    <div class="mover_grab">
        <div class="base_node_frame">
            <div class="base_node_header"><div class="mover_icon"></div><span>To Do List</span></div>
            <div class="base_node">Second div I would also like to be able to move around independently like in Windows</div>
            <div class="base_node_footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mover" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained the problem you are trying to solve. So I'm going to offer AN answer for how you could approach this.

Web Sockets.

Let the web browser handle the complexities of resizeable windows and all that other stuff. Allowing you to focus on the easy display stuff with basic HTML and CSS.

User Opens;

1. /Page-1
2. /Page-2

Then Web Sockets handle the communications between the two.

Not sure if this is relevant, but something to consider given there is no context on the underlying problem trying to be solved.